# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined" Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using Vue Cli but giving this error! I am trying to Register and then move to Index page. But router is not working here.

In main.js I used router for NProgress, here it is working but why not in this case??

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
Vue.use(VueRouter);

import router from './Router/routes.js'

import User from './Helpers/User'
window.User = User

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
  router,
}).$mount('#app')
```

**User.js**

```
import Axios from "axios";

class User {
    register(data) {
        let uri = 'http://localhost:8000/api/auth/register';
        let self = this;
        Axios.post(uri, data).then((res) => {
            self.$router.push({name:'Index'})
        }).catch( (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
}

export default User = new User();
```

**Register.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="card card-container">
      
      <form name="form" @submit.prevent="handleRegister">
       ----
      </form>
   
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
   data() { return { user: {} }},
   
     methods: {
    handleRegister() {
        this.registration();
      });
    },

    registration() {
        User.register(this.user);
    }
  },
   
}
</script>
```

**routes.js**
import components are okay. I also import `Vue` and `VueRouter` here.

```
const routes = [
    //
];

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes
})


export default router
```

What is the problem here?? `router` is working in `main.js`

Giving me error in this line:

> self.$router.push({name:'Index'})

Comment: i think you have your `methods` property declared wrong. why is there another `methods` embedded in it?

Comment: this is a mistake. In code it's okay.

Comment: console.log `self` inside your `.then()` and see if the `$router` property is present.

Comment: No. `router` is not present in console.log()

Comment: can you try `this.$router` instead of `self.$router`

Comment: The given answer is correct

Answer (score 1):

`Vue-Router` will not work in custom js file file like `User.js`

Use it in Vue Component. Like:

**Register.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="card card-container">
      
      <form name="form" @submit.prevent="handleRegister">
       ----
      </form>
   
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
   data() { return { user: {} }},
   
     methods: {
    handleRegister() {
        this.registration();
      });
    },

    registration() {
        User.register(this.user);
        this.$router.push({ name: 'Index'});
    }
  },
   
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is correct but what the case of the registration failure !, so try to add a callback as parameter then call it inside then :

```
class User {
    register(data,cb) {
        let uri = 'http://localhost:8000/api/auth/register';
        let self = this;
        Axios.post(uri, data).then((res) => {
            cb()
        }).catch( (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
}
```

```
   registration() {
        User.register(this.user, ()=>{this.$router.push({ name: 'Index'});});
        
    }
```